# Mapnik - Preserve RGB value of transparent pixels

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, mapnik

Currently generating PNG raster tiles (mapnik) with custom style where I store one information (map_feature) by channel (rgba).
Mapnik seems to multiply alpha with value of red, green or blue. I completly understand the rendering engine case seeing 0 as alpha interpreting as full transparent pixel. I just need it to write the color value anyway.
More explanations on my setup :

I have an OSM Database to deliver PNG raster tiles.
Nothing much to say about the setup - It's working perfectly.

- PostgreSQL
- Mod_tile
- Mapnik

I've setup a new style based on osm-bright in order to display one type of information by channel :

- Channel Red   rgba(255,0,0,1) --> Rivers
- Channel Green rgba(0,255,0,1) --> Water_areas
- Channel Blue rgba(0,0,255,1) --> Forest

Using alpha as 1 and with 3 informations works.
However when i try to swap alpha channel to 0 and add info in alpha channel  :

- Channel Alpha rgba(0,0,0,255) --> Roads
- Channel Red   rgba(255,0,0,0) --> Rivers
- Channel Green rgba(0,255,0,0) --> Water_areas
- Channel Blue rgba(0,0,255,0) --> Forest

When I'm analyzing the raster tile **(the BINARY not with my eyes)** I can't find anymore the value store where as rgb were.
I don't need to see them just disable the interpretation of Mapnik (or agg_renderer).
I've dig deep inside mapnik github code I found this :

[Github - Mapnik: test/unit/imaging/image_premultiply.cpp](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/blob/094994ef540353b846490bf5c0dd127d00740dcb/test/unit/imaging/image_premultiply.cpp)

It seems to be a function called set_premultiplied_alpha() which could explain why (255,0,0,0) pixel is interpreted as (0,0,0,0).

How can I fix my problem?